# How to convert strings like "19-FEB-12" to epoch date in UNIX

Tags: bash, unix, date, unix-timestamp

In UNIX how to convert to epoch milliseconds date strings like:

```
19-FEB-12
16-FEB-12
05-AUG-09
```

I need this to compare these dates with the current time on the server.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To convert a date to seconds since the epoch:

```
date --date="19-FEB-12" +%s
```

Current epoch:

```
date +%s
```

So, since your dates are in the past:

```
NOW=`date +%s`
THEN=`date --date="19-FEB-12" +%s`

let DIFF=$NOW-$THEN
echo "The difference is: $DIFF"
```

---

Using BSD's `date` command, you would need

```
$ date -j -f "%d-%B-%y" 19-FEB-12 +%s
```

Differences from GNU `date`:

1. `-j` prevents `date` from trying to set the clock
2. The input format must be explicitly set with `-f`
3. The input date is a regular argument, not an option (viz. `-d`)
4. When no time is specified with the date, use the current time instead
   of midnight.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. To run:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {

    n = systime()

    FS="-"
}

{
    t = mktime(sprintf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", "20" $3, convert($2), $1, 0, 0, 0))    

    printf "%.1f days ago\n", (n - t) / 60 / 60 / 24
}

function convert(m) {

    return(((index("JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC", m) - 1) / 3) + 1)
}
```

Results:

```
358.6 days ago
361.6 days ago
1286.6 days ago
```