# How can I convert a string into date with different timezone in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to convert a date string in IST timezone format to date in GMT timezone.

Date String:

```
2017-01-29 08:58:09 IST
```

Expected Output:

```
2017-01-29 03:28:09 GMT
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14805591/1531971

Comment: `man date` is your friend

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `date`:

```
$ TZ=GMT date -d '2017-01-29 08:58:09 IST' +'%F %T %Z'
2017-01-29 03:28:09 GMT
```

The `-d` option specifies which time to print (instead of "now"), the `+'%F %T %Z'` output format string is short for `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z`, and `TZ=GMT` sets the `TZ` environment variable for the command to `GMT`.