# Converting string value to epoch time in Unix Ksh shell

Tags: date, unix, ksh, epoch, hp-ux

Can somebody please tell me how to do string value conversion to epoch time in ksh shell (HP-UX). My string value is of format "`20170610 08:18:30`". I was able to do this in bash using `date -d"$stringdate $stringtime" +%s`. Also `date +%s` doesn't work in ksh, I have used `perl -e "print time"` to get epoch time but I am unable to convert my string to epoch value.

Comment: Please run `type date` either in bash as in ksh and check, if results are the same. What happens when you run `date +%s` in ksh?

Comment: Running this command in Ksh gives error. It says &amp;quot; bad format character - s&amp;quot;. I think date command option &#39;+%s&#39; is not supported in Ksh. Perl or mathematical formula should be used instead.

Comment: What about `type date` results? Did you check that?

Comment: type date in bash gives output :- date is a tracked alias for /bin/date. Same command in ksh shell gives output :- date is a tracked alias for /usr/bin/date. Also, I am using different server for bash and ksh.

Comment: type date in bash gives:- date is tracked alias for /bin/date and same command in ksh gives output:- date is a tracked alias for /usr/bin/date

Comment: So, it has nothing to do with the shell, but with the date implementation on those machines.

Comment: Thanks for the information Artur. But then how do I make the conversion on that machine? I searched everywhere but couldn't find any. I need to get epoch value from the string. Is their any other way to do this conversion.

Comment: Check the BSD section from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14805690/2989411). If it won't help, google for: "how to convert data string to epoch in <insert your favourite language here>".

Comment: what version of ksh are you using?

Comment: I am using HP-UX B.11.11 U 9000/800