# Generating a bash script to handle datetime stamp

Tags: bash, date, datetime

I have thousands of backup files that are of the general format PICU_XX-YYYYYYYYYYY.Stp, where XX is a number and YYYYYYYYY is a Unix timedate stamp. Searching these files manually is difficult and erroneous when I use the windows file date and time.  I want to be able to search for these files by using the unix datetime stamp generated.

**Sample File Structure**

```
./PICU_06-1328483198.Stp
./PICU_06-1328580000.Stp
./PICU_06-1329124034.Stp
./PICU_06-1329593129.Stp
./PICU_06-1329868449.Stp
./PICU_06-1329934425.Stp
```

I am trying to generate a small program that will take an input date/time, convert it to the Unix timedate system, and then find the files that are closest to the date/time.

Date example: 02/18/2012 17:25:29

Location example: 06

The date would convert to 1329607529.  The next step would be to find the closest file before and after that time and date stamp.  So it would take PICU_06 and find     ./PICU_06-1329593129.Stp  &  ./PICU_06-1329868449.Stp

**Start of my code:**

```
echo Please enter LOCATION to search for. EX: 01 13 09A 22
read location
echo thanks
echo --------------------------------------------------

echo Please enter time to search for in MILITARY time.  Ex: MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS
read startdatetime
echo thanks
echo --------------------------------------------------

date --date=\'$startdatetime\' +"%s"
```

As it stands, I can't get the datetime to work within the script to generate the second half of filename to search for.

**Some of the errors i get are:**

date: extra operand ‘+"%s"’

date: the argument ‘02:34:33'’ lacks a leading '+';
when using an option to specify date(s), any non-option
argument must be a format string beginning with '+'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert strings like “19-FEB-12” to epoch date in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805591/how-to-convert-strings-like-19-feb-12-to-epoch-date-in-unix)

Comment: Similar - but I want to script it such that I input a date/time.  That seems to be where this is falling apart for me.

Comment: You might want to try to change `--date=\'$startdatetime\'` to `--date="$startdatetime"`

Answer (score 0):

Specify an input date format before output the timestamp:

```
date -jf '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' $startdatetime +"%s"
```

Comment: I get the following error: date: unknown option -- j

Comment: I use cygwin64, if that matters.

Comment: Alright, maybe the easiest thing to change is your input format.
Indeed, according to the man, it seems that Cygwin follows the GNU date spec without that option.
(http://www.polarhome.com/service/man/?qf=date&af=0&tf=2&of=Cygwin).
Try to use '2004-02-29 16:21:42' format instead of your former one.